# How can I read Background Intelligent Transfer Service (BITS) log?

Tags: logging, microsoft-bits, bits-service

How can I read Background Intelligent Transfer Service (BITS) log?

I found the following blog:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/heaths/archive/2008/07/07/enable-bits-logging.aspx

but it's creates binary log file that I can't read on

> %WINDIR%\System32\bits.log

Any one can help me?

Answer (score 0):

It should open using Windows Event Viewer.